# Binding ViewModel events outside of the init

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

I am using RxSwift and Swinject in my project. The way I bind the inputs / outputs is not exactly the same as in the example given by RxSwift. In [RxExample/GitHubSignup](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/blob/main/RxExample/RxExample/Examples/GitHubSignup/UsingDriver/GithubSignupViewModel2.swift), the binding is done in the `init()`, right? But I found it difficult to implement because I use Swinject+SwinjectStoryboard to do Dependency Injection to the View Controller. Thus, the `init()` is unavailable because the one instantiating the View Models is the Swinject container. So, is there a way to bind the view controller and view model together besides using `init()`?

I was thinking that I can maybe use `var` instead of `let` for the output observables and make a func `bind(observables: [Observable])` or something that will do the bindings and transformations from input to output instead. But because they will be vars and not lets, that means it seems like we are permitted to change the bindings throughout the code. Unlike when we just use lets and bind them in the `init()`. And also, by using a function instead of the initializer, I have to store the dependencies into a member variable. While if I use the initializer, I can just transform the dependencies inside of a `map` or `flatMap`.

And also I have another question. Say, if I have this:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var refreshButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var viewModel: MyViewModel!
    private let disposeBag = DisposeBag()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        viewModel = MyViewModel(refreshTap: refreshButton.rx.tap, dataProvider: ApiAdapter().getData)
    
    }
    
    private func setupEvents() {
        viewModel.tableDTOs.bind(to: tableView.rx.items(
            cellIdentifier: reuseId, cellType: TableViewCell.self)) { _, dto, cell in
                cell.fill(with: dto)
        }.disposed(by: disposeBag)
    }
}

final class MyViewModel {
    let tableDTOs: Observable<[TableDTO]>
    
    init(refreshTap: Observable<Void>, dataProvider: () -> Observable<[TableDTO]>) {
        tableDTOs = Observable.merge(.just(), refreshTap) //Merge with .just to emit at once for initial values
             .flatMapLatest { dataProvider().asDriver() }
    }
}
```

So in this case, if the dataProvider returned `complete` or `error`, the disposable will be disposed, right? So the scene will be unresponsive because the UI is already unbound. Any idea how to fix that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So, is there a way to bind the view controller and view model together besides using `init()`?

Yes there is. Give the view model a function that takes the inputs and returns the outputs.

> But because they will be vars and not lets, that means it seems like we are permitted to change the bindings throughout the code.

Don't ever make an Observable (or Subject, or Observer) a `var` always use `let` Functional Reactive Programming is a functional paradigm so no vars.

> So in this case, if the dataProvider returned complete or error, the disposable will be disposed, right? So the scene will be unresponsive because the UI is already unbound. Any idea how to fix that?

Yes and no. If the dataProvider emits a completed event, that will not dispose because the `flatMapLatest` only disposes if *all* of its inputs complete. Since the `refreshTap` has not yet completed, the `flatMapLatest` will continue to accept events from it and call it's closure for each one.

If the dataProvider emits an error event, that *will* dispose because and error event short circuits the chain. However, since you use `.asDriver()` on your dataProvider, the Driver returned from the closure can't possibly emit an error event. You're safe.

Other ways of stopping the error from breaking the chain are to use `.materialize()` or any of the `.catchError` operators. For example:

```
.flatMapLatest { 
    dataProvider
        .map { Result<[TableDTO], Error>.success($0) }
        .catchError { Observable.just(Result<[TableDTO], Error>.failure($0) }
}
```

Comment: I see. So the whole binding of inputs and outputs would be from that function, right? That means I don't have to store the outputs as a member variable, right? Thanks.

Comment: Exactly correct. If you keep going down this road, you will begin to wonder why you are even putting the function in a class to begin with. 